# Name of a late 70s early 80s TV show

Tags: story-identification

The only thing I remember about the program itself was a narrator speaking while light is flashed on carousel animals and the carousel began to them move w/ accompanying creepy music.  It was on just before "Fright Night" on Channel 9 in New York at 11:30.  It was eventually replaced by "Tales from the Darkside"  in the scheduling. Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

The show was "[Tales of the Unexpected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_the_Unexpected_%28TV_series%29)" which originally aired in 1979 and continued into a 9th season in 1988.

This [youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/TheShipSong1/search?query=tales) has many episodes available to watch online